# IE Edge do not call FileReader.onerror method when there is an error

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, filereader

I'm using FileReader to detect if the given blob is file or folder using the 'readAsText' method. I have the following code:

```
  testFileOrFolder(file) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const fileReader = new FileReader();

      fileReader.onload = (ev) => {
        resolve({isFile: true}); 
      };
      fileReader.onerror = (error) => {
        resolve({isFile: false}); 
      };

      fileReader.readAsText(file);
    });
  }
```

When there is file IE edge hits the **'onload'** method and all works fine.

In other case, when there is folder the **'onerror'** method is not triggered.
That happens only in IE Edge.

There is an error in a console, but I cant handle it even with try/catch.

Comment: You said there is an error in console, can you try to share the detailed error message or a snapshot of the error message may help us to understand the issue in better way. do you use any HTML control to select the file? I seen some examples in which it does not produce any error if you select the folder. It simply opens that folder to select the file.

Answer (score 0):

I add try/catch statement and it works. The working code is:

```
  testFileOrFolder(file) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const fileReader = new FileReader();

      fileReader.onload = (ev) => {
        resolve({isFile: true}); 
      };
      fileReader.onerror = (error) => {
        resolve({isFile: false}); 
      };

      // Catch fileReader Error for IE Edge
      try {
        fileReader.readAsText(file);
      }
      catch (err) {
        resolve({isFile: false}); 
      };
    });
  }
```

Event that the Microsoft documentation says that the **'onerror'** is supported, but it may depend of the browser version